# Direct sum definition

Tags: linear-algebra

> We say that $V$ is the $\textit{direct sum}$ of subspaces $U_1,\ldots,U_m$ if every element $v \in V$ can be written uniquely as the a sum $u_1 + \cdots + u_m$ where each $u_j \in U_j.$

I need help understanding the definition. What do we mean by $v$ can be $\textit{"written uniquely"}$ as a sum $u_1+ \cdots + u_m?$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That means there does not exist another set of $\{w_1, \dots,w_m\}$, with $w_j\in U_j$  for each $j$, and where $u_j \neq w_j$ for at least one  $j$, but $w_1 + \dots + w_m = v \in V$.

Comment: do you mean "but $w_1+ \cdots+w_m=v \in V$?"

Comment: @user167857 Yes. That was a typo.

Comment: Yes.I added some detail to make sure that it is clear.